# Jetbrains IDE(s) failures

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

First my specs are an Intel i7 toshiba laptop with 8gigs of RAM running windows 8.1 with all the latest updates. When I first launch any of Jetbrains IDEs after install, it would ask me for my workspace location and then it would proceed to do nothing after than, but it stays in memory and slows down my entire system for about a minute, after that, the computer stops being slow and returns to normal but the program still does nothing (no GUI) but still remains in memory, what is going on??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine with my windows 8.1, so it's definitely not the issue. Try to remove folder with all settings (caches, plugins, etc):http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181 and start IDE.

Comment: Nope, same thing occurs

Comment: Well IMHO in this case contacting JetBrains support is a good idea: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new .

Comment: I have, still awaiting response.

Comment: Well, it's Sunday, so I believe they'll answer you on Monday.:)

Comment: JW do you have any AV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the jre folder within the IDE folder (pycharm,intelliJ,etc.) with one from an updated JDK install not JRE install.

ex:
JDK/jre7 copy over Jetbrains/IDE/jre

fixes the issue

Comment: can you explain this answer with more detail? I have the same issue and couldn't resolve yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard giving a definite answer to your question. But it sounds to me like you have a problem with your Java. Make sure you have it installed and at the latest version.

Also, try looking for matching bugs in the **[JetBrains bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)**.

Comment: Java has been uninstalled and reinstalled to it latest version, I update the JRE regularly but I did it just in case if it was defective, same problem. Also, many users has had NSIS installer issues, I dunno if thats what it is, but I install fine, just can't run.

Comment: @TrayTray I don't know what to tell you. Like I said, it's difficult diagnosing it with the information you have. Perhaps you should try and file a customer support query with JetBrains.

Comment: I did, I have yet to hear from them, but thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @TrayTray Wait around, perhaps someone else may be able to help you.

Comment: ok will do, I love using the Jetbrains IDEs in the past, I just hope its not a windows 8.1 compatibility issue.

Comment: @TrayTray Maybe try running it in compatibility mode with Window 7? Although that never helps XD